Getting build error: the `#[global_allocator]` in spl_token conflicts with global allocator in: spl_associated_token_account
Earlier I was able to build my solana programs using anchor build but suddenly getting strange error error: the #[global_allocator] in spl_token conflicts with global allocator in: spl_associated_token_account, I tried doing cargo clean, anchor clean and even removed Cargo.lock file still getting the error. Can someone help me please?
anchor version = 0.30.0
solana-cli = 1.18.12


Programs typically define an entrypoint and also a heap to be used with their program, which means that their program crates also contain that code.
The current convention is to include a no-entrypoint crate feature to exclude that code. For example, here's that feature for the spl-associated-token-account: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/61794be356d80a02023eeddce326a71727f7b8c4/associated-token-account/program/Cargo.toml#L11
When specifying other program crates in your program's Cargo.toml, you need to enable that feature, ie:
spl-token = { version = "3", features = ["no-entrypoint"] }
spl-associated-token-account = { version = "2", features = ["no-entrypoint"] }

